# $T(a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2)=2a_{0}+a_{2}+(a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2})x+3a_{2}x^2$- Finding $[T]_{E}^{E}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T(a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2)=2a_{0}+a_{2}+(a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2})x+3a_{2}x^2$ be a linear transformation. I need to find the eigen-vectors eigenvalues of $T$.

So, I'm trying to find $[T]_{E}^{E}$  when the base is $E=\{1,x,x^2\}$.

I don't understand how I should use this transformation to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to write the $3\times3$ matrix which represents $T$ in the base $E$.

Comment: This is exactly what I don't know to do with this transformation.

Comment: in $R^n$, which matrix takes $(a_0, a_1, a_2)$ to $(2a_0 + a_2, a_0 + a_1 + a_2, 3a_2)$? It will be the same matrix as $[T]_E^E$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify an arbitrary polynomial $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ with the vector $[a_0\ a_1\ a_2]^T$. So $T$ is the mapping
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix} 2a_0+a_2 \\ a_0+a_1+a_2 \\ 3a_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The matrix that does just that is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Write the vector $a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}$ in the basis E, and represent it as $$\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_{0}\\
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\end{array}\right].$$

Then notice $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 3\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_{0}\\
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
2a_{1}+a_{2}\\
a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}\\
3a_{2}\end{array}\right].$$

What can you conclude from this?

Answer (score 2):

The columns of the matrix you seek are the coordinates of the images under $T$ of the elements of the basis. So you need only compute $T(1)$, $T(x)$, and $T(x^2)$.

Comment: How do you compute T(1) in this kind of transformation?

Comment: $1 = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$ where $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = a_2 = 0$. Plug into your formula...